# How to sort string rotations without using a matrix

Tags: algorithm, string, sorting

I want to sort the rotations of a string.
For example:

For `S = 'abaeb'`, a rotation could be `'baeba'`

I need to obtain a list of indexes to `S`, sorted in lexicographical order.
In our example: `V = 02413`.

The answer must exclude the trivial matrix rows sort.

Comment: If you specify your problem more, I can give a more specific answer. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Edited: after pointed by Justin Peel

Just append the string to itself `bbaeb` becomes `bbaebbbaeb`(a handy trick for problems involving rotation of string).
Find suffix array.
Traverse it and only select the values less than the length of orignal string(5) .
Suffix array for above string

```
aeb  7
aebbbaeb  2
b  9
baeb  6
baebbbaeb 1
bbaeb 5
bbaebbbaeb 0
eb  8
ebbbaeb  3

S = 7 2 7 6 1 5 0 4 8 3
```

Now aftertraversing Ans= `2 1 0 4 3`

### Edit over

You can solve it in O(n) time complexity with the use of [Suffix array](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=5DEBF88A50A941C482A6EE8DEEF5E5DD?module=Thread&threadID=627379&start=15&mc=30http://). Basically suffix array for a string contains index of all suffix of a string in lexicographic order.
For string abaeb, the suffix in lexicographic order are:

```
abaeb (0)
aeb   (2)
b     (4) 
baeb  (1)
e     (3)
```

So the suffix array `S=02413`

Code with O(n log^2n) time complexity is given at that link with detailed explanation and next page have optimization for O(n).
If you want to keep your code simple then using a comparison operator as already answered is the key. And if your of main concern is efficiency then use o(n) suffix array construction.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the correct answer to what the OP is asking. The OP was asking for sorted rotations, not sorted suffixes. Am I wrong? It works out to be the same thing for the example that was used, but using 'bbaeb' instead will generate different results for sorting rotations vs. sorting suffixes with a suffix array.

Comment: @Justin Peel : Sorry for missing that fact and thanks for pointing it out. I am editing the solution.

Comment: I just solved this problem after looking at Burrows-Wheeler transforms on Wikipedia.  Searched Google for "sort string rotations" and found this page, where the top answer was the same as the one I thought of!  +1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have an input string, and you are considering all rotations. For example the N rotations of an N-length string would be, e.g.:

```
rotations("abcd") -> ["abcd"*, "dabc", "cdab", "bcda"]
```

You wish to write a comparator function, `compare(rotation1, rotation2)`, which will say whether `rotation1` is < or > or == `rotation2`, in the *context* that the *original rotation was `abcd`, or alternatively, have a function `key(rotation)` which is equivalent to the above comparator function.

If this is incorrect, please clarify the question. =) If it is correct, your answer is as follows:

```
original = 'abcd'

letterPositions = defaultdict(set)
for i,letter in enumerate(original):
    letterPositions[letter].add(i)

def numIndicesRotated(rotated):
    possibilities = set(range(len(original)))
    for i,letter in enumerate(rotated):
        possibilities &= {(j-i)%len(original) for j in letterPositions[letter]}
        if len(possibilities)==1: #optimization
            break                 #optimization

    if len(possibilities)==1:
        return possibilities.pop()
    else:
        raise Exception('not a rotation')
```

Note that rotations may not be cleanly unorderable if you have a string which has rotations that are itself, e.g. `abcabc`.

Then you can do something like `sorted(myRotations, key=numIndicesRotated)`

Comment: Beware, the OP is talking about _rotations_ which is only a special case of _permutation_.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for sorting, you don't need to keep all the sorted items in memory in parallel, you need just to be able to compare any pair of them.

What i mean, you can sort indexes of string rotation beginning (i.e. 1 = 'baeba', etc) and provide a comparison method which will compare the rotations based on that index.

While the complexity is not better than `nLog(n)`, the code should be very simple. Also, memory complexion is close to the best u can get. Somehow exploiting the knowledge that the sorted items are not random, might probably give you better complexity (but i currently have no idea how to do it).